# SQL model follows to retrieve previous notifications

Tags: sql, postgresql

These are my tables:

```
Author
author_id text

Client
client_id text

Post
author_id text
post_id text

Follow
client_id text
author_id text
```

I am having trouble modeling the follow table to achieve the following:

1)Client can fetch all the posts from authors which he is currently following

2)Client can follow then unfollow then follow and so on...

3)Whenever an author adds a post, clients receive a notification for the post(this is done through another service(firebase) which doesn't provide a way to fetch previous notifications)

4)Client can fetch all previous notifications he received(i'm having trouble with this point)

Does anybody have an idea how to model my tables to be able to query for the last point.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to track the history of a client following an author, rather than just the current state, then you need effective start and end dates on your Follow table.

This will also allow you to track theoretical notifications (i.e. when a notification should have gone out). If you want to track actual notifications then you would need your notification process to record successful notifications in a table.

Your Post table also need a date column